# Multiplication of data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 3 datasets in one 40×7 double data set and I want to multiply these and plot the result over a time period. My question is how to do that.

My attempt has been to divide the datasets into 3 individual cells of data and call them `A`, `B` and `C` (each with 40×3) by using the operator `a=[{A}]` and so on.
Next, I multiplied them with each other by using `.*a.*b.*c` and with the time `t=[0:40]` (which is the x-axis).

I get the following error and I don't know what to do.

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Anyone that can help me?

---

*Code as provided by OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243939/multiplication-of-data-in-matlab#comment63909535_38243939):*

```
a = ans(:,1:3);
b = ans(:,4:6);
c = ans(:,7:9);
A[{xyz}];
B=[{a}];
C=[{c}];
t=[0:41];
D=(A.*B.*C);
plot(D,t);
```

Comment: what exactly is the error ? and could you post your code in code format ? and I assume your dataset is 40x9 and not 7 or how can be three times 40x3 be 40x7?

Comment: the error is: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: please post your code and the exact line the error occurs  ... you can edit your question and then mark you code in code format ... then its easier to see

Comment: otherwise looking at it I would assume your problem is 0:40 are 41 entries, while your matrix is just 40 entries long

Comment: a = ans(:,1:3);  <br/>
     
b = ans(:,4:6);    <br/>
c = ans(:,7:9);    <br/>    


A[{xyz}];  <br/>
B=[{a}];<br/>
C=[{c}]; <br/>
t=[0:41];<br/>
D=(A.*B.*C);<br/>
plot(D,t);<br/>

Comment: ans is the file with all the data from a , b and c. I can't upload it here :S

Comment: Sorry, have to wait for 5 minutes to be able to edit it :P But it should be a new row after every ; . Sorry

Comment: @Newbie_01 Please consider accepting one of the answers if they solved your question. It's the check mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to combine `reshape` and `permute`, and take the product along the third dimension.

Assume the following is your data. This will be 40x9 in your case.

```
rows = 4; cols = 6; N = 2;
x = ceil(10*rand(rows,cols))
x =
     9     6     1     6     5     8
     6     9     9     5    10     6
    10     9     7     9     6     3
     7    10    10     3     9     7

r = permute(reshape(x, rows, N, []), [3,1,2])
result = prod(r,3).'
result =
    54     6    40
    54    45    60
    90    63    18
    70    30    63
```

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your code, it seems unnecessary to create a cell from it:
you can for example:

```
ans=rand(40,9);
a = ans(:,1:3); b = ans(:,4:6); c = ans(:,7:9);
D=a.*b.*c;
t=[1:40];
plot(D,t)
```

or

```
ans=rand(40,9);
    a = ans(:,1:3); b = ans(:,4:6); c = ans(:,7:9);
    D=a.*b.*c;
    t=[0:39];
    plot(D,t)
```

Your t vector has to have the same length as your inital matrix - your matrix has 40 rows but the vector you create by `t=[0:40]` is 41 entries long so you either do `t=[1:40]` or `t=[0:39]`

and if t is your x-axis you should plot it in the right order so `plot(t,D)` instead of `plot(D,t)`

Comment: Hmm, I tried your code and it is giving the following error:  Error using plot Vectors must be the same length.

Comment: did you change t to 0:39 or t=1:40 ?

Comment: Sorry, it worked. The plot looks like a mess, but still giving something

Comment: well you dont need the first line of my code i hope you get that ... I just created random data!

Comment: The problem in the plot is that  the code didn't multiply the data sets with each other. It's just a plot with the data plotted separately :/

Comment: can you upload your data on some open file sharing platform and post the link here ? and edited your question with a picture of what you expect ... if you multiply using .* command you dont multiply matrixes but you multiply the  values element by element

Comment: Sorry buddy, my computer died and I didn't have a charger with me. I tried this and it worked! I had a different set of data earlier, the wrong one. Thanks for the help!